# Does linux "rename" function call block until copy(when source and target in different disks) is completed

Tags: c++, c, linux, file

If an C/C++ app call rename(https://linux.die.net/man/3/rename) function where 'newpath' is in a different disk volume/partition and assume the copying from current path to new path consume time.
Does'rename' call block until copying from current to new is completed ? or does it return immediately (or quickly) while copying happen asynchronously ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: If the implementation does support rename across different filesystems (but I'm not aware of any that do), there's no inherent reason it would need to block until data is physically moved. It merely needs to confirm that there's sufficient space on the destination volume in order to be able to report an error vs success. Any subsequent failure like problem with the physical media or loss of power is outside the scope of the standard (rather, a non-conforming implementation), in that the standard supposes faithful reproduction of data saved.

Comment: In the very back of my mind I think I remember having observed exactly this, `rename()` blocking when renaming from one mount to another. This was under zLinux roughly 10 years ago.

Comment: @alk Linux never supported `rename(2)` accross different filesystems. The `mv(1)` utility does more than a `rename(2)`.

Comment: The man pages don't state `rename` is non-blocking, and don't state it is asynchronous. The same applies to [Posix `rename`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html). Why would you think either applies? Can you share a link to a doc that specifies the behavior?

Comment: @mosvy: Your are right, my memory cheated on me. :}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine it would return immediately with an error code:

```
Errors

The rename() function shall fail if:

[...]

EXDEV
The links named by new and old are on 
different file systems and the implementation
does not support links between file systems.
```

That said, I don't have a Linux box handy to test with, so I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Indeed this is what happens.

Comment: But what happens if the process starts correctly then fails for one reason or another, for example if the link is broken during the process? It seems to me that `rename` cannot return any value before the process is finished completely

Comment: Yes, you're right; however, since the process doesn't involve copying a file, it should be relatively fast (in particular, it shouldn't take any longer for a large file than for a small file).  Note also that the Linux filesystem does write-caching, which means that in most cases the `rename()` call needs only update the in-RAM-memory cache-structures before returning; changes to actual disk blocks will be written out to the hard drive by the filesystem-cache, later on.